Doubly Optimal Filter
Context: The Kalman filters are optimal when the noise structure is Gaussian. Now I have a somewhat more nuanced scenario. The signal goes through 2 sequential channels where the second one is Gaussian and, as well, we can optimally filter the first channel. Now can we say if the Kalman filter is an optimal filter for the composite channel?
More formally, suppose that $X_t$ is a square integrable martingale with respect to some filteration $\mathcal{F}_t$ defined on a complete probability space (with no assumption on Gaussianity or conditional Gaussianity of $X_t$ for $t\ge0$). Assume that $X_t$ is only partially observed through another process $\xi_t $ and the optimal filter is denoted by $Y_t =\mathbb{E}[X_t|\sigma(\{\xi_t\}_{[0,t]})]$. Now, let $Y_t$ be again partially observable through another process $\xi'_t$ but this time through an additive Gaussian noise: $dZ_t = dY_t + \sigma_z dW_t$ where $W_t$ is a Wiener process. We can think of it as a signal that is transmitted through two channels and the second channel adds a normal noise. Can we still say the optimal filer for $X_t$ with respect to $\sigma(\{\xi'_t\}_{[0,t]})$ is linear in the second $Z_t$ observable signal?
My guess is "yes", because it seems only the innovations w.r.t. the second channel matters for the optimal filter but I don't see how adding an arbitrary additive Gaussian noise suddenly made an non-optimal filter optimal.
